Nonsignificant individual level paths in GIMME network model output
I used the R package gimme to create individual level network models using repeated measures data from each person in a 95 person sample.
The code ran successfully, but looking at the individual path estimates spreadsheet from the output, I see that many participants have at least a few paths with p-val > .05 that still show up on the plot and the spreadsheet. My understanding was that non-significant paths at the individual-level are pruned from the results, so I'm not sure what's up with these.
Looking around online I did see that one of the package authors posted “When looking at the individual-level plots, a path indicates significance, as long as it's not a group-level path.” Not sure whether this applies thought because many of the paths showing up are not significant group-level paths.
Wondering if these paths be interpreted as significant or non-significant?
